# How to undo > 1 in Squeak

Tags: smalltalk, undo, squeak

How do you undo in squeak more than one time? I am using coglinux-VM, Squeak-Image 4.5 with Squeak source version 41.

I wrote some test code in my workspace window and want to undo more steps, but Squeak won't do it.

Comment: Can you share what you've tried already?

Comment: Hi @JimGarrison, I just wrote some test code in my workspace window and want to undo more steps, but Squeak won't it. It is a Squeak internal problem, not a code problem.

Comment: Note that the linux flag is not really relevant: since the undo support is at image side and not vm side, it is OS-agnostic.

Answer (score 3):

Support for multiple undo has been dropped in 2009 when integrating the TextEditor from Cuis. This is findable in Morphic package history (or at http://source.squeak.org/trunk/Morphic-ar.149.diff)

Cuis is a fork of Squeak aiming at a simpler code in general, and particularly a simpler Morphic (all code must be understandable by a single programmer but yet remain powerfull), See http://www.jvuletich.org/Cuis/Index.html.

It sounds like main usage of the TextEditor is in the Browser, and that the methods are short enough to not really require a multiple undo... At least there were no complaints until then, and I guess the drop was un-noticed. It is even possible that it might have been accidental rather than deliberate...

However, the object used for storing multiple undo history is still there (EditCommand) and there is even a Preferences (multipleTextUndo) that is currently unsent but could be restored...

It would be a good exercize to see how hard/easy restoring this feature would be. A good start is tracking usage of EditCommand and multipleTextUndo in an old version of Morphic.

Comment: > “At least there were no complaints until then, and I guess the drop was un-noticed. It is even possible that it might have been accidental rather than deliberate...” | Well, I had from my students and just wondered myself. I then thought it was my fault.

Comment: Hi @aka.nice: Correct. I began to write small code snippet in the browser and tried to undo some entries. For beginners (like me) it is helpful to have sample codes in the browser to try some methods/messages.

Comment: How to contact the dev community about this missing feature? Is there a good channel for it?

Comment: @bartak the main channel for squeak development is the squeak-dev mailing list. There is also a bug tracker (mantis) at bugs.squeak.org, not really in good health, but still usefull.